# Settings Keys from a Database as Variables in PHP

Tags: php

My apologies as I am sure the answer is obvious.  But I am new to PHP... a transplant from ColdFusion.  I have a MySQL table called settings the holds key pair values that I want to set as site-wide variables in php. For instance:  page_title => 'Untitled Page', site_title => 'Sirius FireWeb'.

Here is my function that grabs the data from the database:

```
function get_sitesettings(){
global $db;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM settings WHERE autoload = 'yes'";
$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
confirm_result_set($result);

$result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
confirm_result_set($result);
return $result;}
```

Here is where I call the function and thought I could loop through the query results and set the variables, but I really have no idea how to do it in PHP.

```
$get_settings_result = get_sitesettings();
while($settings = mysqli_fetch_assoc($get_settings_result)) {
// SET THE VARIBLES HERE USING THE QUERY OUTPUT?
}
$page_css = array();
$no_main_header = false; 
$page_body_prop = array('class' => 'smart-style-1 fixed-header'); 
$page_html_prop = array();
```

Can someone please provide guidance on how to set keys as variable names in PHP?

Comment: _how to set keys as variable names in PHP_ What do you actually want to achieve that is not possible with using your results array? Sounds to me like a xy-problem

Comment: Sounds like I may be approaching this all wrong.  So if anybody has suggestions on how I should be using commonly used values from a database, I am all ears.

Answer (score 0):

```
${$settings["key"]} = $settings["value"];
```

But I don't think it's a good idea.

Comment: In the database, I have a key named “site_title” and the value is “Sirius FireWeb”.  I was thinking I need to set it as a variable so it can be used on the pages where needed.  Right now $page_title is hard coded into the init page with the value of “Sirius FireWeb”.  That page_title variable is used several times on each page load.  One for the header title, one for the breadcrumb and I think one for the menu system.

Comment: Is there a better way to use commonly used sitewide variables from a database?  BTW... your solution worked.

Comment: Why don't you just keep those data in some config file?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try the extract() on the results?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php